# Story about movie characters inside a TV

Tags: story-identification

Story is probably from the 60's to early 80's, told in first person by a movie character in a TV. At one point he mentions another character named Black Bart. He can see out through the screen, where a couple watches on a couch until they get to cuddling. Character realizes what he's missing and goes nuts. The last line is, "LET ME OUT OF THIS DAMN BOX!"

Answer (score 8):

The story is "Double Standard" by Fredric Brown, from the collection "Paradox Lost".

"It is true, then!  There is no censorship for them.  They can and do do the things that in our world can only be vaguely suggested as off-screen happenings.  How can they be free when we are not?  It is CRUEL.  Let me out of here.  Let me out of this god damn box."[image]